Error download the file from blob storage for "BlobDownloadHeaders.getContentLength()"
@Override
    public byte[] getBlobAsByteArray(String customerId, String docTypeId, String fileName, boolean isUser) {
        String blobName = formBlobName(customerId, docTypeId, fileName);
        BlobClient blobClient = configureBlobClient(blobName, isUser, false);
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            blobClient.downloadStream(outputStream);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MSSNotFoundException("Failed to download blob for docTypeId: "+docTypeId, e.getMessage());
        }
    } 

Error:
java.lang.Long.longValue()" because the return value of "com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobDownloadHeaders.getContentLength()" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Long.longValue()" because the return value of "com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobDownloadHeaders.getContentLength()" is null
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.getBlobLength(ModelHelper.java:467)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobAsyncClientBase.lambda$downloadStreamWithResponse$18(BlobAsyncClientBase.java:1289)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:178)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2864)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:261)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2573)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:246)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8891)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:196)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:178)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:176)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:435)
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNe


Can you add more info on question?

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


Error download the file from blob storage for "BlobDownloadHeaders.getContentLength()

The error occurred due to getContentLength() method returning null. This method is used to get the length of the content that is being downloaded from the blob storage.
You can use the below code that will check the blob size and will download the content as byte array using Azure Java SDK.
Code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String customerId = "customer123";
            String docTypeId = "doc456";
            String fileName = "example.txt";

            byte[] blobData = getBlobAsByteArray(customerId, docTypeId, fileName);
            System.out.println("Blob downloaded successfully, size: " + blobData.length + " bytes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error downloading blob: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] getBlobAsByteArray(String customerId, String docTypeId, String fileName) {
        String blobName = formBlobName(customerId, docTypeId, fileName);
        System.out.println(blobName);
        BlobClient blobClient = configureBlobClient(blobName);

        try {
            // Check if blob exists
            if (!blobClient.exists()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Blob does not exist: " + blobName);
            }

            // Fetch blob properties and log metadata
            BlobProperties properties = blobClient.getProperties();
            System.out.println("Blob Size: " + properties.getBlobSize() + " bytes");

            // Download blob content
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                blobClient.downloadStream(outputStream);
                return outputStream.toByteArray();
            }

        } catch (BlobStorageException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("BlobStorageException occurred: " + e.getErrorCode(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOException occurred while downloading blob: " + blobName, e);
        }
    }

    private static String formBlobName(String customerId, String docTypeId, String fileName) {
        return customerId + "/" + docTypeId + "/" + fileName;
    }

    private static BlobClient configureBlobClient(String blobName) {
        return new BlobClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING)
                .containerName(CONTAINER_NAME)
                .blobName(blobName)
                .buildClient();
    }

The above code will check if the blob exists, fetches its properties, and downloads its content as a byte array. Finally, it logs the size of the downloaded blob.
Output:
customer123/doc456/example.txt
Blob Size: 1739 bytes
Blob downloaded successfully, size: 1739 bytes


Reference:
Download a blob with Java - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
